# Changing the type of the elements in a nested list

Tags: haskell

I have the object `tableaux :: [[[Int]]]` and I want to change it to `[[[Int32]]]`. I do:

```
int32ToInt :: Int32 -> Int
int32ToInt = fromIntegral

tableaux32 = map (\y -> map (\x -> map intToInt32 x) y) tableaux
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: `tableaux32 = (fmap \`fmap\` fmap \`fmap\` fmap) intToInt32 tableaux`

Comment: @melpomene I think using `fmap` where you could use its specializations, `map` and `.`, is unnecessarily confusing. I also don’t think that using `.` is any clearer than just writing `map (map (map intToInt32)) tableaux`.

Comment: @AlexisKing Yeah, but my way is funnier.

Comment: @melpomene I can’t argue with that. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider that `(\x -> map f x)` is simply `map f`. How many times do you see this pattern in your function? I see it twice.

Comment: This should be a comment, it's just a tip for the OP.

Comment: Ah yes, indeed. Thanks. But then nesting the `map`'s is a nice way ? Ok.
@syntagma I understand the "tip", it could be an answer then.

Comment: I finally prefer `map (map (map fromIntegral)) tableaux :: [[[Int32]]]`, no need to introduce a function like this.

Comment: I disagree, @syntagma. It's not a tip, it's the answer, but phrased in a way that means you have to read it and think for a second instead of copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0):

While in this example you can get away with a simple chain of `map`s, whenever you have deeply nested structures you should reach for lenses.  There are multiple packages for that in Haskell, one of the most powerful is Edward Kmett's [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens).

With lens you can use for example `traverse` to focus each element of a `Traversable` container:

```
convert :: (a -> b) -> [[[a]]] -> [[[b]]]
convert = over (traverse . traverse . traverse)
```

The power of [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) is that you can also have a `[Vector [Maybe a]]` instead and the same function `convert` will still work after generalizing the type signature.

As Daniel Wagner noted in the comments you can still do the above example by using only `fmap`.  The intention was to highlight that lens generalizes this pattern of modifying nested structures very nicely and should be preferred once those modifications get more complicated.

Comment: No need to reach for `lens` to achieve the feature you list in your last sentence. `fmap (fmap (fmap intToInt32))` does that just as well.

Comment: Yeah right, maybe the example was not chosen well ;)  There are a lot of cases that you cannot solve with `fmap`.